# How to find eigenvalues of a linear operator consists of laplacian?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, boundary-value-problem, mathematica

I have the following matrix of linear operator consists of Laplacian \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\\Delta&\Delta& 0\\0&0&\Delta\end{bmatrix}
acting on \begin{bmatrix}w\\w_t\\u\end{bmatrix}, where $u=u(t,x)$ is the velocity of fluid/heat , $w(t,x)$ is the structural displacement. So it is a fluid-structure interaction problem, where $u=0$ on fluid boundary, and $u=w_t $ on structure boundary. How could I find eigenvalues of it? How to use Mathematica/Matlab to get eigenvalues?

Comment: What is $I$ supposed to denote in this context?

Comment: Also, is the $\Delta$ supposed to be the laplacian over $x$ (so just the second derivative) or is it over (x,t)?

Comment: I is Identity or 1 here@Ben Grossmann

Comment: Laplacian over x only @maxmilgram

Comment: Have you tried to write down the three differential equations and solve them?